# Javascript syntax checking within a JSP file not working

Tags: javascript, eclipse, jsp, eclipse-wtp, syntax-checking

I'm using eclipse 3.5 with WTP 3.0 to develop a web app using JSP and Javascript etc. Sometimes I need to embed Javascript code directly into a JSP file eg. to use a string out of the resource bundle message. My problem is, that I can not find a way to turn on Javascript syntax checking within a JSP file. Can somebody help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the JSDT wiki page, it appears that syntax checking and other features of the Javascript editor are not built into the JSP editor. I have the same complaint.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/JSDT

Note that not all the Javascript editor extension points are supported yet. I am assuming these extensions are necessary in order to integrate the Javascript editor features you want into the JSP editor.